# Python HashTable & linked lists. How to print a list from the HashTable class

Tags: python, hashtable, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment and what I have to do is make a hash table (hash value x^2 % tablesize) and when given a key value I have to add it to the hashtable. But, if two keys have the same hashvalue I have to make a linked list at that slot in the hashtable. Here's my code...

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def add(self, data):
        temp = self.head
        self.head = Node(data)
        self.head.next = temp

    def __str__(self):
        str_list = []
        current = self.head
        while current:
            str_list.append(str(current.data))
            current = current.next
        return "[" + "->".join(str_list) + "]"

# Implement the missing functions in the ChainedHashTable ADT    
class ChainedHashTable:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.links = [None] * size
        self.size = size

    def insert(self, key):
        #Make 'lst' equal to LL/None at given key in hash table
        lst = self.links[self.hash(key)]

        #Check to see if spot at hash table is None. If so, make new LL.
        if lst == None:
            lst = LinkedList()
            node = Node(key)
            lst.add(node)
            self.links[self.hash(key)] = lst
            return

        #Else append key to already existing linked list.
        node = Node(key)
        lst.add(node)
        return

    def hash(self, key):
        hash_code = (key*key) % self.size
        print(lst)
        return hash_code


# Sample testing code
# You should test your ADT with other input as well
cht = ChainedHashTable(11)
cht.insert(1)
cht.insert(36)
cht.insert(3)
cht.insert(44)
cht.insert(91)
cht.insert(54)
cht.insert(18)
print(cht)
```

I get the following error when the print(cht) occurs...

```
<__main__.ChainedHashTable object at 0x0000000002D9E2B0>
```

Output should be...

```
[[44], [54->1], None, None, None, [18], None, None, None, [91->3->36], None]
```

Note: Adding...

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.links)
```

Gave me an error: Max recursion depth exceeded.

Thanks a million if you can help me out at all.

```
def __repr__(self):
    final_list = []
    for i in range(len(self.links)):
        if self.links[i] == None:
            final_list.append('None')
        else:
            link_list = self.links[i]
            string = link_list.__str__()
            final_list.append(string)
    return ', '.join(final_list)
```

With that code I get the following..
[<**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C518>][<**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C5F8>-><**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C358>]NoneNoneNone[<**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C6A0>]NoneNoneNone[<**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C588>-><**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C470>-><**main**.Node object at 0x0000000002E5C400>]None

Why isn't it converting the contents of the linked list into a string (with given function) then assigning that string back to the self.links[i]? I can't see where the issue is in that code..

SOLVED
When I was adding my nodes to my linked list I was adding the node object NOT the node data. Thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: Don't go through `links` and *replace* the entries with strings. If you do that, all your data is lost. You just have strings left.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: Make a new list for display purposes!

Comment: Hey, I modified the code up there. I don't modify self.links in any way - I just pull values out of it. Now, I have no clue why it doesn't work... I even tried putting the __str__() code directly into the repr function, but the result was the same. The good news is, I have all my nodes in the right place, so, my output is correct, I just need to print it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses `__repr__` when displaying objects in containers. You will need to implement for all three classes:

```
class Node:

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class LinkedList:

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

class ChainedHashTable:

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.links)
```

Also, to avoid a `NameError`, remove `print(lst)` from `ChainedHashTable.hash`.

Comment: Hey, I tried doing that but I got the following error...

builtins.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Comment: I tried itterating through self.links and turning each element in self.links into a string by the __str__() function in LinkedList, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? You can just `map(str, self.links)`

Comment: Well, the error I got was 'returned none string' list object.
Sorry, I'm somewhat new to python, what do you mean by map(str, self.links) ?

Comment: Yes, you have to return a string! `map(str, self.links)` gives the result of applying `str` to every item in `self.links`.

Comment: Even if the element in self.links is a linked list? Also would I put the map(str, self.links) under def__repr__(self): return map(str, self.links)

Comment: `map` doesn't return a string; see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map). It will (try to) apply the first argument to everything in the second argument.

Comment: Ran the code, but...
builtins.TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type map)
I got that error.

Comment: Did you actually read my last comment? Review the first five words!

Comment: Yeah, I did. My issue is how to implement it. If I cant put it under a def __str__ or def __repr__ function then what's the point in having it? When I got to print(cht) the map function will be out of the picture entirely. Anyways, thanks for the help, but it doesn't seem like this is a workable solution, atleast, not with the knowledge base I'm working with.

Comment: I don't know where you're putting these methods, but I have updated my answer to show exactly what is working fine here for me.

Comment: Ahh, I wouldn't have guessed to put them there, but, for my assignment I'm not allowed to touch the code in the node class nor the linkedlist class. Sorry, I should have stated that in the original question.

Comment: Then you will have to work through all layers in `ChainedHashTable.__repr__`; start by stealing the code from `LinkedList.__str__` and wrapping it in `for item in self.links`

Comment: Hey, I added some code up there. Any idea why that doesn't work? I've gone and made a string of every element in self.links, but it give me the right output..

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work, maybe pull more of the code from `LinkedList`